# How can I rotate my images directly from the finder?

Tags: keyboard, finder, preview, quicklook

I would like to rotate my images directly from the Finder.

The best would be one of these:

- a button to click in the menu bar of every Finder's window
- a button to click in Quicklook

But, if it can be done with a keyboard-shorcut, it would be fine also.

Is one of these features possible? And if yes, how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can use Automator to make a service for Finder (or all applications) to perform rotation of images. Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut to that action.

[image]

I'm not aware of quicklook plug-in that rotate, but that's something that might exist. Modifying finder's shortcut bar might be the least likely way to activate things, but hopefully an Automator service (or app / droplet) will do.

Comment: It's a good answer and seemed to fit exactly what I needed - but it seems incredibly slow. Rotating and saving in preview happens faster. In fact, rotating once in the finder using automator is slower than opening, rotating, saving and closing it in Preview. I have 8,000+ images to rotate so hopefully I'll find something that can be as quick as preview but in the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

In Mojave press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+A, then right click > Quick Actions > Rotate Left.

This has the side effect of updating the icon on the Finder.

Comment: And also have the side effect of lossing EXIF infos...

Comment: The EXIF data will be lost because to rotate the image, the image data has been loaded into a new graphics data context, transformed, and then re-saved as a new file. (Unless the action's code saves and restores the EXIF data.) Some image formats have rotational metadata, where you just can set the display angle. Many of Apple's own Automator actions for image manipulation are badly implemented, despite the underlying graphics APIs being able to do it properly.